# Bootstrap/JQuery Accordion. Button Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, class

This is what i'm trying:

[image]

[image]

As you will see, the collapse works well (I did it on html, using button classes), but now the thing is; for example, when I click the buttons of Jimi Hendrix div sound the other songs too, because they have the same Bootstrap class.
I tried to name the buttons of the different div's with different id's but doesn't work. The code:

//HTML

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Songs</h2>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Creedence Clearwater Revival<small> I Heard it Through the Grapevine</small></a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="buttons">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg button-skip-backward">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-backward"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg button-pause">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg button-stop">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg button-play">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg button-skip-forward">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-forward"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <audio src="CCRGrapevine.mp3" id="ccr"></audio></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Jimi Hendrix <small> Hey Joe</small></a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="buttons">
                <button type="button" id= "enrera" class="btn btn-default btn-lg button-skip-backward">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-backward"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" id= "pausa" class="btn btn-default btn-lg button-pause">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" id= "stop" class="btn btn-default btn-lg button-stop">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" id="play" class="btn btn-default btn-lg button-play">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" id="endavant" class="btn btn-default btn-lg button-skip-forward">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-forward"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <audio src="heyjoe.mp3" id="jimi"></audio></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Note that I tried to do this with the id's:

//JQuery and JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log("ready!");
var audioElement = $("#ccr")[0];
var audioElement2 = $("#jimi")[0];


$(".button-pause").on("click", function() {
    $(".button-pause").blur();
    $(".button-pause").addClass("active");
    $(".button-play").removeClass("active");
    audioElement.pause();
});

$(".button-play").on("click", function() { 
    $(".button-play").blur();
    $(".button-play").addClass("active");
    $(".button-pause").removeClass("active");
    audioElement.play();
});

$(".button-stop").on("click", function() {
    $(".button-stop").blur();
    $(".button-play").removeClass("active");
    $(".button-pause").removeClass("active");
    audioElement.pause();
    audioElement.currentTime = 0;
});

$(".button-skip-forward").on("click", function() {
    $(".button-skip-fastword").blur();
    audioElement.currentTime += 5;
});

$(".button-skip-backward").on("click", function() {
    $(".button-skip-backward").blur();
    audioElement.currentTime -= 5;
});

  });
```

I tried to do this but all the songs are playing:

```
$("#pausa").on("click", function() {
    $("#pausa").blur();
    $("#pausa").addClass("active");
    $("#play").removeClass("active");
    audioElement.pause();
```

My question is, how can I disable, for example, the buttons of the first div when I click on another div, in order to play just the song i want?

Comment: Use $(this) to reference target element inside click function and $(".class") for all elements with class name. Target element to activate specific action and all elements to clear their previous states.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using $(this) to refer to a specific button

Try the following

```
$(".button-pause").on("click", function() {
  $(this).blur();
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(this).siblings(".button-play").removeClass("active");
  var audioElement = $(this).siblings('audio');
  audioElement.pause();
```

});

Then modify the other click handler accordingly

Hope it works

Comment: siblings get you the closest brother of a certain class (in this case .button-play)

audio is the tag where you have the audio src (<audio src="CCRGrapevine.mp3" id="ccr"></audio>)

Comment: I understand. I've tried like this but doeasn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parent of the button that is clicked and use the id of that parent div element which is in your case `collapse1` , `collapse2` etc.

.parent() gives you the immediate parent element. Care must be taken while nesting and calling the .parent() function.

An example based on your submitted code:

```
$(".button-pause").on("click", function() {
    var id = this.parent().parent().parent().attr('id');

    $("#"+ id +" .button-pause").blur();
    $("#"+ id +" .button-pause").addClass("active");
    $("#"+ id +" .button-play").removeClass("active");
    audioElement.pause();
});
```

You should apply the following code on all jquery .on() events.

Comment: what should i get with:
     var id = this.parent().parent().parent().attr('id');

Comment: you will get the id `collapse1` for a button clicked in :  `<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">...</div>` similarly id of other divs. depending on which song they select the button from.